# TypeError: "type" object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add another programming language named "Lua" to Python and there is function named string.sub

But there is a problem :

it is my code :

```py
#Lua in Python

class string:
    def find(stringVariable, stringValue):
        output = stringVariable.find(stringValue)
        return output

    def sub(stringVariable, indexValueStart, *indexValueEnd):
        indexValueStart = int[indexValueStart]
        indexValueEnd = int[indexValueEnd]
        output = stringVariable[indexValueStart:indexValueEnd]
        return output

    def gsub(stringVariable, stringIndex):
        stringN = stringVariable[:stringIndex] + stringVariable[stringIndex + 1:]
        return stringN
        #gsub is not finished yet

a = input()

b = string.find(a, "abc")

c = string.sub(a, b, 5)

print(c)
```

It gives this output(error) :

```
nnnabcmmm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mimi Mimiyov\Desktop\lua.py", line 23, in <module>
    c = string.sub(a, b, 5)
  File "C:\Users\Mimi Mimiyov\Desktop\lua.py", line 9, in sub
    indexValueStart = int[indexValueStart]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```

Comment: Do you have to keep that `*` in front in the indexValueEnd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int` is a function, so you can do `int()` instead of `int[]`
And remove the `*` in the indexValueEnd

```
class string:
    def find(stringVariable, stringValue):
        output = stringVariable.find(stringValue)
        return output

    def sub(stringVariable, indexValueStart, indexValueEnd):
        indexValueStart = int(indexValueStart)
        indexValueEnd = int(indexValueEnd)
        output = stringVariable[indexValueStart:indexValueEnd]
        return output

    def gsub(stringVariable, stringIndex):
        stringN = stringVariable[:stringIndex] + stringVariable[stringIndex + 1:]
        return stringN
        #gsub is not finished yet

a = input()

b = string.find(a, "abc")
print(b)
c = string.sub(a, b, 5)

print(c)
```